# Dual of axiomatic cohesion for polynomial functors over sets

Tags: ct.category-theory, topos-theory

Write $\mathsf{Poly}$ for the category of polynomial functors (sums of representables) and natural transformations between them (a full subcategory of $[\mathsf{Set},\mathsf{Set}]$).

We have functors $\mathsf{Poly}\underset{\mathrm{ev}_1}{\overset{\mathrm{ev}_0}{\rightrightarrows}} \mathsf{Set}$ given by evaluating the "polynomial" at zero and at one.

In the other direction, we have two *fully faithful* functors $\mathsf{Poly}\underset{Ay}{\overset{A}{\leftleftarrows}} \mathsf{Set}$ (defined by their action on a set $A$).

The functors above form an adjoint quadruple $Ay\dashv \mathrm{ev}_1\dashv A\dashv \mathrm{ev}_0$.

---

**Question.** What is the geometry underlying this adjoint quadruple, and how to interpret the dual cohesion?

Comment: Just curious, how $Ay$ is defined explicitly?

Comment: please, call it "hesion"